# Adding values in adjacent cells (of column 2) for desired variables in column 1

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

In my data.frame I have a column with a list of items and a column with each item's amount. Each item belongs to a group. I want to calculate the sum of amounts for a selection of items across all groups and enter a value in a new column based on the sum.

Here is my table:

| GROUP | ITEM | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | AT | 20 |
| 1 | EP | 5 |
| 1 | S | 5 |
| 2 | AC | 10 |
| 2 | A | 5 |
| 2 | P | 61 |
| 2 | SB | 39 |
| 3 | Z | 25 |
| 3 | AC | 80 |
| 3 | P | 80 |
| 3 | *na* | 0 |
| 4 | Z | 0 |
| 4 | M | 100 |
| 4 | *na* | 0 |
| 4 | *na* | 0 |

The statements I want to apply:

- if a group contains any of A, AT, EP, AC then perform calculations
- if A+AT+EP+AC >= 80 enter "red" in new "SUM" column for all values in group
- if A+AT+EP+AC <= 20 enter "yellow" in new "SUM" column for all values in group
- if 20< A+AT+EP+AC >80 enter "orange" in new "SUM" column for all values in group
- if a group DOES NOT contain any of A, AT, EP, AC then enter "black"

I tried using mutate with multiple SUMs that I coalesced into SUM, but I can't figure out how to apply the calculations.

This is what I want:

| GROUP | ITEM | AMOUNT | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | orange |
| 1 | AT | 20 | orange |
| 1 | EP | 5 | orange |
| 1 | S | 5 | orange |
| 2 | AC | 10 | yellow |
| 2 | A | 5 | yellow |
| 2 | P | 61 | yellow |
| 2 | SB | 39 | yellow |
| 3 | Z | 25 | red |
| 3 | AC | 80 | red |
| 3 | P | 80 | red |
| 3 | *na* | 0 | red |
| 4 | Z | 0 | black |
| 4 | M | 100 | black |
| 4 | *na* | 0 | black |
| 4 | *na* | 0 | black |

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr::case_when()`?

Comment: Resolve you previous question first?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but you could give this a try - you may have to adjust the regex if the sample data doesn't contain all possible values from ITEM. I flipped your > for Orange because what you had didn't make much sense and the flip made the output match what you have as an expected output.

```
df = data.frame(GROUP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                ITEM = c("A", "AT", "EP", "S", "AC", "A", "P", "SB", "Z", "AC", "P", NA, "Z", "M", NA, NA),
                AMOUNT = c(10, 20, 5, 5, 10, 5, 61, 39, 25, 80, 80, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0)) 

df1 <- df %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(in_group = paste(ITEM, collapse = " ")) %>% 
mutate(SUM = ifelse(grepl("^A| A|AT|EP|AC", in_group), "TBD", "black")) %>% 
mutate(amount_placeholder = ifelse(grepl("^A$|^AT$|^EP$|^AC$", ITEM), AMOUNT, 0)) %>% 
group_by(GROUP) %>% summarize(total = sum(amount_placeholder), SUM = first(SUM)) %>% 
mutate(SUM = ifelse(SUM == "black", SUM, ifelse(total >= 80, "red", ifelse(total <= 20, "yellow", ifelse(total > 20 & total < 80, "orange", NA))))) %>% right_join(df, by = "GROUP") %>% 
select(GROUP, ITEM, AMOUNT, SUM)
```

In the future, a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) makes it much easier to help you -- you can use the `data.frame()` function I use above or `dput`